# A measurable map in Banach space and simple functions.

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

I'm looking for a counter exemple (with proof please) of a mesurable map 
$$
f : X \rightarrow E
$$
with $X$ a measurable space et $E$ a $\mathbb{R}$ Banach space. Such as $f$ is not the limit of sequence of simple functions.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: My measure theory is a bit rusted, but wasn’t a measurable function by definition a function, which can be approximated by simple functions?

Comment: @PrudiiArca The definition they have in mind is probably that $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for every $U\subset E$ open.

Comment: @Aweygan Oh alright. I dont know this definition, so I wont be of much use here :)

Comment: For any set $X$, $(X, P(X))$ is a measurable space and every function $X\to E$ is measurable.

Comment: Not a limit in what sense of convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be any non-separable Banach space, $X=E$ with the Borel sigma algebra. Let $f$ be the identity map of $X$. Then $f$ is Borel - Borel measurable. If there is a sequence $(f_n)$ of simple functions converging pointwise to $f$ then the range of $f$ would be contained in the closed subspace generated by  countable set (namely the union of the ranges of $f_n$'s). But the range is $E$ which is not separable.

Comment: What is the range of $f$ ? Do you mean $\text{im}(f)$ ?

Comment: And why $\overline{\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{im}(f_{n}})$ is separable ?

Comment: @CechMS If you haeve  a countable set $(x_n)$ in  a normed linear space and $M$ is the closed subspace spanned by $x_n$'s then $M$ is separable. This is because rational linear combinations of $x_n$'s form a  countable dense set.